# Android R8 not obfuscating packages since Gradle plugin 7.0.X

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, obfuscation, android-r8

I was obfuscating an Android library code and architecture for my costumer but since I upgraded to the Gradle plugin 7.0.X, the generated `classes.jar` begun to be weird...

First, some classes were moved to a root `a` package instead of `my.lib.package` which should be the root of any classes... I finally used the `-flattenpackagehierarchy my.app.package` to get rid of it.

However, a second weird behavior I have seen is none of the packages inside the `my.lib.package` were obfuscated and I am struggling to resolve this :/ I got a look at the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code), the [Proguard doc](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage), the [R8 FAQ](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/compatibility-faq.md) & the [Unofficial R8 doc](https://r8-docs.preemptive.com/) but none of these helped me.

I also tried to use Proguard instead of R8 thanks to their [doc](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/setup/gradleplugin) but my classes which were inheriting from `View` have not been renamed due to a keep rule in the `proguard-android-common.txt` file both used by `proguard-android.txt` & `proguard-android-optimize.txt` so I cannot get rid of it, FYI:

```
# From the default AGP config: keep constructors that are called from
# the system via reflection.
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
```

So is any of you has achieved a complete obfuscation (class name & packages, except those kept on purpose in the `proguard-rules.pro` file) ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards :)

Comment: You will not be able to have the sub-classes of view renamed. Views are referenced from XML files by name and inflated using reflection to instantiate the view classes. From what I can see you are building a library, so I suggest that you use `-keepparameternames` to allow code completion for consumers of the library. Then use 
`-keeppackagenames my.lib.package` and `-repackageclasses my.lib.package.internal`. to ensure you library package stays and as many classes as possible are moved into an `internal` package to not confuse consumers by avoiding code completion of renamed classes.